# OO concept for establishing connection

Tags: asp.net, web, database-connection

Is there a way I can apply OO concept to adding a connection string to a query? I have to enter the connection string again and again whenever I want to write a query in asp.net

Answer (score 2):

```
public class dbhandler
{
    private SqlConnection con;
    private string ConnectionString;

    public dbhandler()
    {
        ConnectionString ="Your connection string here";

    }

    public SqlConnection Connect()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    }
}
```